# SummerNote Information / notification area not displayed

Tags: notifications, summernote

I am trying to get notification area in summer note to work but It doens't showup.
In the example below I expect the area to show at the bottom once the button is pressed.

What am I missing ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Summernote</title>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
  <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="test()">hello</button>
  <div id="summernote"><p>Hello Summernote</p></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#summernote').summernote();
        $('#summernote').summernote({
        maxHeight: 300,
  dialogsInBody: true,
  dialogsFade: true  // Add fade effect on dialogs
});

    });

    function test(){
    $('.note-status-output').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
    'This is an error using a Bootstrap alert that has been restyled to fit here.' +
    '</div>'
    );
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```